# OnDelete also delete file

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Using EF4.1  is there a event of function I can override on my POCO that will be called when it is deleted?  I save images on the file system with the DB containing a reference to the file. When I delete from the DB I also want to delete the matching file.

Comment: I don't know which database system you're using, but starting with SQL Server 2008, you might want to use a varbinary(max) FILESTREAM column, which transparently stores file inside the file system rather than inside the database. You don't have to manager file deletion manually by using it.

Comment: @Julien Yes I am using SQL 2008 rc2 and that I also my preferred solution. However my hosting provider changes a fortune for SQL space but regular disk space is very cheap so I am trying to keep the DB size down to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `SaveChanges` method of your `DbContext`.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Deleted);

    foreach (var deletedEntity in deletedEntities)
    {
        if (deletedEntity .Entity is MyEntity)
        {
             //delete the file
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can wrap the file delete and database update in a single transaction as follows

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //your deletion logic

    myContext.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in a database level trigger. EF is not the proper place to handle this.

Comment: EF is the only 1 place that will be accessing my DB.  I do not like putting logic, file systems calls in the DB.  Is EF capable of doing it at all?